# padding breaks overflow-y: scroll

Tags: css, scrollable

Hello i'm trying to keep the size of my page the size of the viewport. And for that I have a div that can scroll through many other div.It works well but as soon as I add a padding (even if it's 1px) to the children div of the scrollable one, i can scroll on my page to the right and the bottom. I'm confused as to what is causing that. Any idea ?

Here's the html part of the `class="store"` div that is scrollable with the sections inside it :

```
<div class="store flextwo"> 
    <section onclick="buyMinou(1)" class="cathand">
        <div>
            <div class="image flexone">
                <img src="" alt="cathand">
            </div>

            <div class="minou_info flextwo">
                <div class=minou_name>
                    Cat Hand
                </div>
                <div class="minou_fps">
                    <div class="base_fps flexone">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="total_fps flextwo">
                        [Total clickValue]
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="minou_price_qty">
                    <div class="minou_price flextwo">
                        [Price]
                    </div>
                    <div class="minou_quantity flexone">
                        [Quantity]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Also I should mention that there are 8 of the `section`. They all have the same tags, only thing that changes is the function `onclick` i call and some text (didn't put all of them in that code cause it's pretty long).

Here's the css concerning the scrollable div and its children

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.store {
  background-color: #6050dc;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.store > section {
  margin: 2%; // Margin doesn't cause an issue unless it's too big. 
  color: #10121b;
  background-color: #94c2c2;
  padding: 10px;  // THIS IS THE ISSUE. When I remove this padding my page isn't scrollable (which is what i want). And my div is perfectly scrollable as i want.
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25%;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}

.store > section:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.store > section > div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I also get the problem with `borders` property. It seems to affect the size of my div and therefore the page adjusts to it.
Both my html and body have a `margin: 0;`.

Also let me know if the issue doesn't seem to be in that chunk of code and you need to see more.

Comment: Could you share a complete code sample of the issue and highlight the padding that's causing the problem?

Comment: @Viktor I adjusted my question. Is that enough to make it more clear and easily understandable ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to include all borders and paddings in the width settings instead of getting them added.

Comment: I added it at the top of my css but adding a `padding` or a `margin` too high still affects the size of my page :/